# How to handle identity fields in GraphQL SPQR

Tags: graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

Let's say I have

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="trade_id")
    int tradeId;
```

When I query this from the database, I will want to get the tradeId. However, when performing a Create, obviously I won't have the tradeId, since the Database is going to generate it when I insert it.

```
input TradeInput {
  tradeId: Int!
...
```

But the schema SPQR is generating for me is setting this field to Not Null, however.

So my question is, how can prevent this field from automatically coming up as Not Null, so I won't have to send it down on Creates, but can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` simply can not be `null`. But you have a few options:

- Turn it into an `ID` scalar type (using `@GraphQLId`) instead of an `Int`
- Give it a default value via `@GraphQLInputField`
- Use `Integer` instead of `int`, as `Integer` is nullable

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense about int/Integer. Btw, any reason you editted your reply to not include the suggestion to use 0.0.6? When I try it, I get Failed to introspect Class [io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.web.HttpExecutor] from ClassLoader. Is that a known issue/is that why you retracted your recommendation?

Comment: @Steve Huh, no. Only because you didn't mention the version you're using here, so I thought it would be confusing to mention it out of the blue. Never heard of the issue you mention before... If you don't figure it out quickly, please open an issue with a minimal example replicating it.